# How to use zookeeper for service discovery in prometheus

Tags: apache-zookeeper, prometheus, service-discovery

I found zookeeper service discovery related doc in prometheus code base, but didn't find any document of how to use it. Could anyone guide me how to use that ? Thanks

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/master/discovery/zookeeper

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#serverset_sd_config

Comment: @dmkvl what kind of data format should I insert into zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

Each zknode in a zookeeper should look like this:

```json
{"serviceEndpoint": {"host": "first-service.svc", "port": 9100}, "additionalEndpoints": {}, "status": "ALIVE"}
```

(thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/65838766/15185772)

One zknode defines one monitoring service.

You can create multiple zknodes in a single root, for example:

/monitoring/first-service.svc

/monitoring/second-service.svc

Then we will configure Prometheus:
Paths can point to a single service, or the root of a tree of services (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)

After that, job in your prometheus.yml config file for Prometheus it will look like this:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'scrape_inventory'
    serverset_sd_configs: # zookeeper service discovery
      - servers: ['zookeeper-domain-name.svc']
        paths: ['/monitoring']
```

Once configured, prometheus will detect your services, which can be added dynamically via zookeeper.